# Is there a way to call assign() more than once in Swift Combine?

Tags: swift, combine, observableobject

I would like to update some variables with values received when handling a newly published value. For example, given:

```
class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var PublishedX: Int = 0
    @Published var PublishedY: Int = 0
    @Published var PublishedProduct: Int = 0
    // ...
    init() {
        productPublisher = Publishers.CombineLatest(external.XPublisher, internal.YPublisher)
            // .assignAndContinue(\.PublishedX, \.PublishedY) // something like this
            .flatMap(MyPublishers.secretMultiplication)
            .assign(to: \.PublishedProduct, on: self)
     }
 }
```

I would like to also assign the new values of XPublisher and YPublisher to variables (PublishedX and PublishedY respectively).

Is there a way to set these two variables and then continue handling the event?

Comment: By the time I call `sink` (after the map) I would only have the multiplied value, not the original two X and Y values.

Comment: I also changed the map to a flatMap to help show the problem

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought the problem was the `.assign` line, but it's the `.assignAndContinue` line. :)

Comment: So you could actually do the assignment as part of the `.flatMap`, or you could have another `.flatMap` that produces a Just or a `.map` that produces `$0`. In other words, you use some sort of map to perform arbitrary code and keep going. But...

Comment: I think the Combine Way is to call `.share()` so that you have two subscribers and just add a `.sink` that assigns to the two variables.

Comment: @matt I was avoiding the `.map()` option in case `.assign()` does something special with `@Published` vars.
Thanks, I'll take a look at `.share()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE

If your deployment target is a 2020 system (like iOS 14+ or macOS 11+), you can use [a different version of the `assign` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)) to avoid retain cycles and to avoid storing cancellables:

```
init() {
    external.XPublisher.assign(to: $PublishedX)
    external.YPublisher.assign(to: $PublishedY)
    external.XPublisher
        .combineLatest(external.YPublisher) { $0 * $1 }
        .assign(to: $PublishedProduct)
}
```

#### ORIGINAL

There is no built-in variant of `assign(to:on:)` that returns another `Publisher` instead of a `Cancellable`.

Just use multiple `assign`s:

```
class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var PublishedX: Int = 0
    @Published var PublishedY: Int = 0
    @Published var PublishedProduct: Int = 0

    init() {
        external.XPublisher
            .assign(to: \.PublishedX, on: self)
            .store(in: &tickets)
        internal.YPublisher
            .assign(to: \.PublishedY, on: self)
            .store(in: &tickets)
        external.XPublisher
            .combineLatest(internal.YPublisher) { $0 * $1 }
            .assign(to: \.PublishedProduct, on: self)
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }

    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []
}
```

Note that these subscriptions create retain cycles. Swift will not be able to destroy an instance of `ProductViewModel` until the `tickets` array is cleared. (This is not a property of my suggestion. Your original code also needs to store its subscription somewhere, else it will be cancelled immediately.)

Also, the existence of `PublishedProduct` is questionable. Why not just a computed property?

```
var product: Int { PublishedX * PublishedY }
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought any active subscriptions would be cancelled when the object was destroyed, not the other way around?
Can you attach multiple subscribers to the same publisher? I thought any new subscriber would cancel any existing subscriptions?

Comment: The `AnyCancellable` return by `assign(to:on:)` represents the subscription and must be stored somewhere, because when it is destroyed, it cancels the subscription. Under the covers, an `assign` subscription must hold a reference to the target of the assignment (in this case, the `ProductViewModel` object), and so storing the `AnyCancellable` in a property of the `ProductViewModel` object creates a retain cycle between the `ProductViewModel` and the subscription.

Comment: Every `Publisher` in Apple's `Combine` framework supports multiple simultaneous subscriptions.

Comment: @robmayoff "Every Publisher in Apple's Combine framework supports multiple simultaneous subscriptions" I'm sure you're aware that that's an oversimplification. You won't get thrown off by another subscription coming along, but you won't necessarily get the result you might expect from the word "simultaneous" unless you also say `share()` as I suggested in my comment.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. But as far as I know, using `share` only really matters if your publisher has side effects. I didn't think it was relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to [check out this library](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt)

From their [ReadMe](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt#assign):

```swift
var label1: UILabel
var label2: UILabel
var text: UITextField

["hey", "there", "friend"]
    .publisher
    .assign(to: \.text, on: label1,
            and: \.text, on: label2,
            and: \.text, on: text)
```